# Small Function with Unique Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have data outlined like below:

```
State   Sort
CA      11
CA      21
CA      11
CA      21
WA      11
WA      12
MT      11
MT      12
MT      21
```

I would like to return the smallest *nth* **unique** number for each state.

This formula works where no duplicates exists:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B$2:B$10/(A$2:A$10=D2),ROW(1:1))
```

However, it (obviously) returns 11 and 21 twice for 2nd and 4th smallest values.

I have played with `FREQUENCY` to get a unique list, but it's not working:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$10=D2,MATCH(B$2:B$10,B$2:B$10,0),0),ROWS(B$2:B$10)-1),ROW(1:1))
```

But can't get that too work either. Any ideas on how to make this work?

I would like to return the following for CA:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B$2:B$10/(MATCH(D2 & "|" & $B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10 & "|" & $B$2:$B$10,0)=ROW($B$2:$B$10)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$10))+1),ROW(1:1))
```

It  checks that it is the first occurrence of the number.

[image]

Comment: This is great Scott. Thanks. However, it fails if I use `WA`. Returns 12 as first number, but not 11. I am researching as well. Maybe was not clear but I need solution that accounts for possible dupes and also cases where single values are there. Also fails altogether for `MT`. FWIW, it also is dependent on order of data. If i resort and place `CA` last it fails for `CA`.

Comment: I see the problem give me a minute to figure it out.

Comment: Perfect! I even placed another out of sort state with three values and it worked. I am curious how the pipe separator made it work?

Comment: I used that to in case you have numbers or letters in both columns.  For example if A was `1` and B was `11` it would also match with A `11` and B `1`.  With the pipe it makes it so `1|11` <> `11|1`

Comment: smart forward thinking :) This data set probably will not go there, but its awesome for future (users to this answer too) :)

Answer (score 2):

This formula will give you the required result

`=AGGREGATE(15,6,B$2:B$10/(A$2:A$10=D2)/(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,B$2:B$10)=0),1)`

`AGGREGATE` finds the smallest value where column A matches D2 and the number isn't included in the cells above

[image]